# (Biblatex) How to suppress page field in footcite if postnote is present?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

For my thesis, I am using the `biblatex` style `oxnotes`, which is a style fairly similar to verbose and uses footnotes.

If I use the `\footcite` command with a postnote specified, for an entry with page numbers (e.g. a book chapter), the footnote will print **both** the page number and the postnote. I would like to tell `biblatex` to suppress the page number in a footnote when a postnote is present.

Currently, a `\footcite` like this:

```
\footcite[1-5]{barkan2003}
```

...will produce the footnote

> Barkan, 'Title', *Journal Title* (2003), **1-20 at 1-5**.

I would like to suppress the pages (i.e. "1-20") in `\footcite` commands where a postnote is specified, such that it reads

> Barkan, 'Title', *Journal Title* (2003), 1-5.

I have tried the following command, but it suppresses the pages field in both the citations and bibliography.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{%
    \iffieldundef{pages}{}{\iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\clearfield{pages}}}}
```

Is there a way to tell `biblatex` to suppress the pages field *only* in `\footcite` commands, and not in the bibliography?

Any help on a solution would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=oxnotes]{biblatex}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{oxref}

\begin{filecontents*}{document.bib}
@article{barkan2003,
  title = {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal Title},
  date = {2003},
  pages = {1-20},
  author = {Barkan},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{document.bib}

\begin{document}
Text.\footcite[1-5]{barkan2003}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex-oxref`'s `oxnotes` citation style is based on `verbose.cbx` and supports all of its options. In particular you can use the option `citepages`, which is documented in the [`verbose` style example](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/70-style-verbose-biber.pdf). (In earlier versions of `biblatex-oxref` some aspects of `citepages` were a bit counter-intuitive, but that was improved in version 1.1, see https://github.com/alex-ball/biblatex-oxref/issues/8.)

- The `oxnotes`-default `citepages=separate` gives you

  > Wolfgang A. Herrmann et al., “A carbocyclic carbene as an efficient catalyst ligand for C–C coupling reactions”, *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* 45/23 (2006), 3859–62 at 3860–1.
- With `citepages=omit` the `pages` field is automatically omitted if the postnote is numeric

  > Wolfgang A. Herrmann et al., “A carbocyclic carbene as an efficient catalyst ligand for C–C coupling reactions”, *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* 45/23 (2006), 3860–1.
- `citepages=suppress` omits the `pages` field even if the postnote is not numeric.
- `citepages=permit` (the default of the standard `verbose` styles) would just show both fields

  > Wolfgang A. Herrmann et al., “A carbocyclic carbene as an efficient catalyst ligand for C–C coupling reactions”, *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* 45/23 (2006), 3859–62, 3860–1.

So you could try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=oxnotes, citepages=omit]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Text.\footcite[3860-3861]{herrmann}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Wolfgang A. Herrmann et al., “A carbocyclic carbene as an efficient catalyst ligand for C–C coupling reactions”, *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* 45/23 (2006), 3860–1.]

---

The `\DeclareFieldFormat` idea did not work because `\iffieldundef{pages}{}{\iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\clearfield{pages}}}` is not a command that prints anything. It only tells `biblatex` to delete `pages` in a certain situation. But `\DeclareFieldFormat` should be used to tell `biblatex` how to print stuff, compare with the default

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}
```

or the simpler

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

A `\DeclareFieldFormat` should always involve a `#1`.

In essence this definition deletes the field in the case you want (and it would not delete the field in the bibliography, because `\iffieldundef{postnote}` would be true there), but it overwrites the definition that tells `biblatex` how to print the `pages` field in the first place, which means that it is always dropped in the output.

Deleting a field only in `\DeclareFieldFormat` could cause spurious punctuation because `biblatex` thinks it printed something when it didn't.

So I would not try and pursue that particular approach any further here.

---

Note that the

```
\RequireBibliographyStyle{oxref}
```

was not required. In general you shouldn't have to use `\RequireBibliographyStyle` or `\RequireCitationStyle` in a document. The style is loaded via `biblatex`'s `style` option (or separately via `bibstyle` and `citestyle`).

Comment: See also https://github.com/alex-ball/biblatex-oxref/issues/8

Comment: Thank you, you beautiful person!!! And thanks as well for the github reference -- hadn't seen that!

Comment: Plus I got the reasoning on `\DeclareFieldFormat` wrong... :(  It must have been Monday!